# Problemas com login usando o sdk do facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-sdk

Utilizo o sdk padrão do login do facebook, onde a documentação pode ser [acessada aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#logindialog).

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fb_login() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '',
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.8'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      getUserInfo();
    }
  }

  function getUserInfo() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday,link', function(response) {
      var data = [];
      data.push({
        name: 'token',
        value: jQuery("#token").val()
      });
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/api/user/create/",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(returnjson) {
          alert("ok");
        },
        error: function(returnjson) {
          alert("erro");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

O problema é que gostaria de usar um botão personalizado.

```
<div class="customBtn btn btn-block loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">
  <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onclick="fb_login()">Entrar com Facebook</fb:login-button>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso ao clicar no botão a primeira vez,

- Se o usuário estiver desconectado do facebook, teoricamente ele deveria chamar a janela popup e solicitar o login pra poder puxar as informações pro meu sistema.
- Se o usuário estiver conectado no facebook, ele puxa as informações pro meu sistema.

O problema é que ao clicar no botão, ele cria o contexto do botão do facebook dentro de um iframe e renderiza dentro do meu botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai sim se o usuário clica novamente no botão que está dentro do meu botão (<strike>algo meio **inception**</strike>) que aparece a janela popup, ou puxa as informações....

Comment: `<fb:login-button` é de algum template engine que está utilizando?

Comment: Nope, de inicio eu usava `<button class="btn btn-block loginBtn loginBtn--facebook" onclick="fb_login()">Entrar com Facebook</button>`, mas eu notei que o `iframe` e o popup só eram criados se eu usasse `<fb:login-button`.

Comment: ou seja, se for de um template engine, é do próprio sdk `//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js`

Comment: É isso mesmo @MarceloBonifazio. Você possui uma *div* como essa: `<div id="fb-root"></div>`?

Comment: não, tentei adaptar `<div id="fb-root"></div>` a minha necessidade, mas encontrei certa dificuldade, to tentando uma outra rota: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: consegui adaptar pra minha necessidade, irei postar a resposta amanhã, mas caso alguém consiga responder antes eu dou o voto

Comment: Legal @MarceloBonifazio. Responde sim, para caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema :)